# Can we write List as a type argument in Generics in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

For Example, function prototype is:

```
 void set<V>(Type a, V b);
```

and we call it as:

```
 int a;
 list<int> b;

set<List<int>>(a,b);
```

Comment: Using the word "Type" is a bad idea in this example because `Type` is a .NET framework class, and there exists .no conversion from `int` to `Type`.  At least, it threw me off for a second.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic constraint such as this:

```
 void set<TList, TElement>(TElement value, TList list)
      where TList: IList<TElement>;
```

Answer (score 1):

(I'll prefix my answer with a reminder of the difference between a parameter and an argument: a parameter is the "placeholder" for something, and an argument is the value that fills a parameter. (Hence the term "parameter argument"). For example class `List<TFoo>` has a parameter called `TFoo`, but instance `List<String>` has an argument `String` for parameter `TFoo`.).

Types are either "generic" or "concrete" (i.e. non-generic).

Generic type parameter arguments can be any type, concrete or generic. A generic type that has all of its parameters filled with concrete type arguments becomes concrete itself; so `List<String>` is concrete because `String` is concrete, but `List<TFoo>` is not concrete because `TFoo` is a type parameter.

So with this, it becomes easy to see that generic classes can be nested recursively, either in their generic form or in a concrete form. Of course you can only use the generic form within a generic class or method context, for example the following is completely legal:

```
private static IEnumerable<List<Dictionary<String,Int32>>> foo = new Collection<List<Dictionary<String,Int32>>>(); // this is completely concrete

static void DoSomething<TBaz>(IEnumerable<List<Dictionary<TBaz,Int32>>> baz) { // this is generic because TBaz is not specified

   List<TBaz> someList = new List<TBaz>(); // you can use the undefined TBaz because it's listed in the generic method's type arguments.
}

static void Main() {
    DoSomething( foo ); // the compiler will infer TBaz from the String argument used in the foo field
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to ask if you can make `Type a` specific to `V`...

if that's your question, then yes, you have to define the method like so:

```
void set<V>(V a, List<V> b)
```

If you meant for `a` to be of type `Type`, then yes to the question of `List<int>` being allowed as a type parameter. Your example wouldn't compile, however, since `a` is `int` and not `Type`.